# Missing executable

Tags: steam, the-game-of-life

I was bored so I decided to buy the The Game of Life. I installed it, but every time I tried to launch it an error came up about a missing executable. I was wondering if there is a way this can be fixed.

Comment: Try to verify the install to make sure everything downloaded properly

Comment: What executable is missing, actually? Can you quote the message you get, or post a screenshot? Could it be a DirectX or Visual Basic or other auxiliary software executable?